# Encryption Decryption libraries like JASYPT

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, encryption, password-encryption

I would like to know whether there are any alternative libraries like JASYPT , which can help me in Encryption / Decryption of passwords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are some. I'm not sure what exactly are you looking for, but I have been using [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) with great success. Maybe it will interest you as well.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the java security API. It includes a large set of security algorithms and mechanisms for various purposes.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136007.html

Answer (score 1):

While looking for implementing crypt functionality, I came across keyczar https://github.com/google/keyczar.

It offers pretty simple api to invoke crypt functions as

```
Crypter crypter = new Crypter("/path/to/your/keys");
String ciphertext = crypter.encrypt("Secret message");
```

It also provides api for java/python/cpp languages, and was originally developed by Google security team.